# New to jstree basics

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have recently started using jstree for a project. I have looked at the documentation on the jstree website and have come up with a very simple tree:

```
<div id="jstree_test"></div>
<script>
$(function () {

$('#jstree_test').jstree({
    core: {
        data: [
                {
                    id: 'parent1',
                    parent: '#',
                    text: 'p1'
                },
                {
                    id: 'child1',
                    parent: 'parent1',
                    text: 'c1'
                },
                {
                    id: 'child2',
                    parent: 'parent1',
                    text: 'c2'
                },
                {
                    id: 'child3',
                    parent: 'parent1',
                    text: 'c3'
                }
        ]
    }
});

});             
</script>
```

When I run this code, all i get is 'p1' with a bullet point linked to itself. My desired code is simply p1 with the three children c1, c2, and c3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the state property to your particular node in your object.

```
$('#jstree_test').jstree({
    core: {
        data: [
            {
                id: 'parent1',
                parent: '#',
                text: 'p1',
                'state' : {
                       'opened' : true,
                       'selected' : true
                 }
            },
            {
                id: 'child1',
                parent: 'parent1',
                text: 'c1'
            },
            {
                id: 'child2',
                parent: 'parent1',
                text: 'c2'
            },
            {
                id: 'child3',
                parent: 'parent1',
                text: 'c3'
            }
    ]
}
});
```

Given a demo in jsbin -- [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/halok/1/)